# All Paragrahps in One Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

As you know, Wordpress automaticaly generate post's html like this:

```html
<h2>Heading Example</h2>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<h3>Heading Example</h3>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<h3>Heading Example</h3>
```

But i wanna make all paragraphs between headings in one div like this:

```html
<h2>Heading Example</h2>
<div class="paragraphblock">
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
</div>
<h3>Heading Example</h3>
<div class="paragraphblock">
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
</div>
<h3>Heading Example</h3>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`nextUntil()`**](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) and [**`wrapAll()`**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) in [**`each()`**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop.

```js
$('h2,h3').each(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil(':not(p)').wrapAll('<div>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Heading Example</h2>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<h3>Heading Example</h3>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<h3>Heading Example</h3>
```

An alternative.

```js
$('h2,h3,p').each(function(){
  console.log(this.tagName)
  if(this.tagName == 'H2' || this.tagName == 'H3'){
    $div = $('<div>');
    $(this).after($div);
  } else {
    $div.append(this);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Heading Example</h2>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<h3>Heading Example</h3>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<p>Text here</p>
<h3>Heading Example</h3>
```